# Generating a Table with 2 Vectors as Columns (R)

Tags: r

If I have 2 numeric vectors `x` and `y`, and I want to render a table with those 2 vectors as columns, how do I go about doing that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get an R matrix? If so, you can use

```
cbind(x, y)
```

provided that the the vectors have the same length. If their lengths differ, you should get a warning stating such.

I hope that this helps!